# Storing / Retrieving App Data Online using Android

Tags: java, android, database

I am new to Java and Android. I am just beginning work on an app that will save information to a server that someone else from within the same company can retrieve using the same app from a different android device. I know how to simply store data on a server using simple php scripts but this is a bit more complex and involves one user writing information to the server, while another user can see / download it. Within a company there would be multiple users who have acceess to this data. So my question would be, whats the best way to implement a company-wide database that ONLY members of the same company can have access to? Sorry if this seems obvious to some of you. I am just getting started and I have 7 books on android programming and none of them describe how to do quite what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use Android **network services** to access data. In other words to **retrieve** a networked database information your device will connect to your service with a specified URL and arguments. In turn, the service will reply with the required data, say may be in XML format. All your app needs to do is parse the XMl and display the date as desired.

Same thing applies to **putting** data into the server, in this case however the data will be sent as arguments to the network service URL and the service will handle the persistence to a database.

My advise is to do a Google search of the keyword "Android Network Services".